# Getting attribute information from layer in OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I just want to add a layer that represents a city with its city districts. When the user clicks on a district, the site fires an alert presenting the population number. It looks like that:

[image: Example]

However, it doesn't work. I also upload a picture of my javascript code: 
[image]

Obviously, I missed something, but I don't find the problem. Can someone help me?
Here is also the GeoJSON file if it's useful.

[image: Result]

Comment: please post the **text** of your code not a picture